# How to update a column using another column's value with a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following scheme.

```
meta_id    meta_key    meta_value
1            key1         5
2            key2       sometext
3            key3       serialized_text
4            key4         8
```

Now I have added a fourth column to my table as the "Numeric Representation" of the `meta_value` column for performance reasons. But I have to update the preexisting data. This is how I need it to be.

```
meta_id    meta_key    meta_value           num_value
1            key1         5                     5
2            key2       sometext               NULL
3            key3       serialized_text        NULL
4            key4         8                     8
```

In a nutshell I need a query to update the fourth column only if the meta_value is a number. I know how should I update a column based on another column. The condition is the part I'm interested in.
Thanks

Comment: It's weird that I can't edit my question. I reach a 404 error page!

Comment: What is the data type for `num_value` column?

Comment: It's `INT` with 32 digits length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET num_value = meta_value * 1 -- or just meta_value
 WHERE meta_value REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+$'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74f55/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks but it updated all the records, not just the numeric ones.

Comment: @HamedMomeni I've updated a pattern in the answer to ensure that a value contains only digits and a comma. See updated answer and sqlfiddle demo. You can ditch a comma from regex if don't expect any decimal values in `meta_value` that should be converted to an int in your update.

Comment: There could also be negative numbers. So I think the pattern should be `^([-]?)[0-9]+$`.

Comment: Yep, it will do the trick. You better tell such details in your question in the first place. Updated answer to reflect that - might be  helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET meta_value = null
WHERE meta_value not regexp '^[0-9]+$';
```

Look at demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a006/1)